# Setting cookie in Javascript name not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in Javascript with this code I found in another post here:

```
document.cookie = 
'username=' + value + 
'; expires=' + expires + 
'; path=/';
```

Thing is, the cookie gets created but with name "username", why does that happen and how can I create one with value as name?

Comment: Are you sure that "value" is not the "username" when you are trying to set it?

Comment: Becuase you creating a new cooke with the name username see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Yes, this goes before: var value = "cookie";

Comment: I don't get it, isn't it supposed to be "name=" + value? being value the actual name?